# Проблема с кодировкой греческих букв Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, tkinter, pdf

Хочу сделать себе словарь греческого языка на python`е. Скачал словарь в pdf. И пытался его вскрыть этим кодом:

```
from tkinter import *
import PyPDF2
root = Tk()
pl = open('C:\\vkbot\\game-py\\dict.pdf', 'rb')
plread = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pl)
getpage37 = plread.getPage(4)
text37 = getpage37.extractText()
    
rawdata=text37.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
opr=''
for i in range(len(rawdata)):
    opr+=str(rawdata[i])
    if i%100==0:
        opr+='\n'
w = Label(root, text=opr)
w.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Получилось вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не силён в кодировках, но мне кажется, что проблема в них.

Comment: `text37.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')` это все равно что число * 2, потом / 2  - результат будет совпадать с исходной строкой. Если text37 вывести просто в текстовый файл, будет там читаемый текст?

Comment: insolor, нет, там будет тоже самое

Comment: Значит проблема в PyPDF2. Попробуйте написать разработчикам.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй указать кодировку при открытии файла вот так - `pl = open('C:\\vkbot\\game-py\\dict.pdf', 'rb', encoding = 'utf-8')`. UTF-8 поддерживает огромное количество символов, вбей "символы юникод" в гугле

Comment: При чтении в бинарном режиме (буква `b` в `'rb'`) выбор кодировки не не работает - при попытке так открыть файл вылетит ошибка "ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument". Указание кодировки работает только при работе с файлами в текстовом режиме.

Comment: извините, не знал) спасибо за инфу